# How can I automatically split text files into parts of a known size?

Tags: linux, windows, textfiles

I'm pondering the feasibility of splitting up a text based ebook into smaller parts to read on an iPod - they need to be about 4 KB each for that. Is there any command or program (Linux or Windows) that would allow me to do this, and hopefully give me output with some indication of the order of the files?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're looking for [`split`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/split), specifically with `-C`.